# Cocos2d android Double tap

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

all .
I am trying to detect double in android  in cocos2d since last 2 days.
But i am not able to get any satification result ...
So , please help mout me to try this issue,
I am counting it in CCTouchEnded and incerment in var on every touch
Any help is appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: what have you wrote in the CCTouchEnded() class ?